# "In between" or "between"?

Tags: prepositions, difference, grammaticality-in-context

- There's a misunderstanding (in) between us.

Is it natural with **in** or without? In which case should we add **in**?

Comment: I would naturally say "there's a misunderstanding between us." You might like to read this [previous English StackExchange question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/what-is-the-difference-between-in-between-and-between).

Comment: **in between** is used only with nouns and pronouns whose referents exist in the physical world and have physical dimension.  **us** is conceptual, so not "in between".  *Put the book on birds in between the one on flowers and the one on bees.*

Comment: I can't understand who downvoted this question. Now everyone knows if they can use **in between** with abstract and non-physical objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *in between* when referring to something physical:

> There is a puddle in between us.

But when referring to something intangible or metaphorical, stick with *between*:

> There is some tension between us.

Note that, in the first case, the *in* is optional; one could just as well say:

> There is a puddle between us.

However, the *in* reads awkwardly when talking about something more abstract, and should therefore be omitted:

> We have a disagreement <strike>in</strike> between us.

<sub>Note: American English; other dialects may treat this differently</sub>

Comment: Okay, so **in between** doesn't work with non-physical entities and generally can omitted? Thanks!