# Is it natural to say "put an adverb in between a phrasal verb"?

Tags: word-usage

When I write the post [What types of adverbs could be put between a phrasal verb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/251460/116345), I have difficulty making a choice between the following options.

1. put an adverb between a phrasal verb
2. put an adverb **in between** a phrasal verb

According to ["In between" or "between"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/140467/116345), both of them are correct, as words could be considered some kind of physical entities.

The question is which one is more natural?

Is it more natural to use "in" for speaking while less natural to use "in" for writing?

Comment: Neither is correct. Try "put an adverb in the middle of a phrasal verb".

Comment: ***Insert*** *an adverb* ***into*** *a phrasal verb.*